# HorizontalTextAlignment - iOS (Not working as intended)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem when using `HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"` on iOS cause it is properly working on Android. The problem is that it is not properly wrapping the sentence to next line as intended.

This is my result:

[image]

Code:

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="3">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Text="{Binding lblItem}"
                       TextColor="#BCBCBC"
                       FontFamily="Calibri"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Label.Margin>
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0,5,0,0" Android="0,5,0,0" WinPhone="0,0,0,0"/>
                            </OnIdiom.Tablet>
                            <OnIdiom.Phone>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0,0,0,0" Android="0,0,0,0" WinPhone="0,0,0,0"/>
                            </OnIdiom.Phone>
                        </OnIdiom>
                    </Label.Margin>
                </Label>

</Grid>
```

How can I properly use the `HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"` to properly wrap it around in a layout?

EDIT: Seems like there is something wrong when wrapping a text that is binded behind the vm, for now I do not know why but, I am trying to look for work around. Gonna keep this post updated if ever I found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem, seems like the Label's `Horizontal/Vertical.TextAlignment` has a bug on iOS if you are binding the Label's Text. In order to fix this I created a CustomRenderer for this label specifically on iOS:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
{
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement == null) return;

        var ctrl = (YourLabel)Element;

        ctrl.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        ctrl.VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to wrap text around, you'll have to set the `Label.LineBreakMode` property to `WordWrap` (see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Label/) and [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.LineBreakMode/)).

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="3">
    <!-- ... -->
    <Label Text="{Binding lblItem}"
        LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <!-- ... -->
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

This should break the text correctly.

Maybe you have to set the `HorizontalOptions` to `Fill` instead of `Center`.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry I have also tried this work around but it did not worked as intended.

Comment: This is no workaround, this is how it's supposed to work, actually.

Comment: Anyway, if this does not solve your issue, could you add screenshots of your whole screen  for Android and iOS?

Comment: I have tried your code (as far as it is possible for me) and the text wrapped both on Android and on iOS

Comment: It seems like I know what's the problem. I tried to remove the binding of the item and it worked as intended. So probably there's something wrong when wrapping the text if binded